# Need help on a implicit differentiation

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Question:

The implicit funtion $z(x,y)$ is given by the equation $\ln{(x+yz)} = xy^2z^3$. Find the directions wich the directional derivative of $z(x, y)$ on the point $(0,-1)$ has value 1.

My attempt:

Since $D_u = <f_x,f_y,f_z> \cdot \ u$ I've tried calculate $f_x , f_y$  and $f_z$ using implicit differentiation finding:

$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}}{\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}} = z^5$

$\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} = \frac{\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}}{\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}}} = -z$

But I dont't know if I can do $f_z = \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{z}} = 1$ and calculate $D_u$ using $f(x,y,z) = <z^5, -z, 1>$

Someone know how to solve this problem? And if there is something wrong on the begin of my solution?

Comment: You need the gradient of $z(x,y)$ which is $(\frac{dz}{dx}, \frac{dz}{dy})$. Then you take the dot product with $(0,-1)$ to get the directional derivative.

Comment: Compute what $z$ must be. Compute ${\partial z(0,-1) \over \partial x}$. Compute ${\partial z(0,-1) \over \partial y}$. Compute $h$ such that $h_1 {\partial z(0,-1) \over \partial x} + h_2 {\partial z(0,-1) \over \partial y} = 1$.

Comment: @JohnDouma: The point $(0,-1)$ is where $z$ is evaluated, not a direction.

Comment: Ahh, I was trying to use the gradient of a function like $f(x,y,z)$

Comment: I've made it again, and found $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -z^5$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -z$, computing the values on z(0,-1) to find each one, the result is $ h = (1,0)$ or $ h = (0,1)$